# JComboBox cascade

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to design a three cascade `JComboBox` in JAVA:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ThreeCascadeJComboBox {

private JComboBox combo1;

private JComboBox combo2;

private JComboBox combo3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ThreeCascadeJComboBox();
}

public ThreeCascadeJComboBox() {
    JFrame v = new JFrame();
    v.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    combo1 = new JComboBox();
    loadCombo1();
    combo1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            loadCombo2((String) combo1.getSelectedItem());
        }

    });

    combo2 = new JComboBox();
    loadCombo2((String) combo1.getSelectedItem());
    combo2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            loadCombo3((String) combo2.getSelectedItem());
        }

    });


    combo3 = new JComboBox();
    loadCombo3((String) combo2.getSelectedItem());

    v.getContentPane().add(combo1);
    v.getContentPane().add(combo2);
    v.getContentPane().add(combo3);
    v.pack();
    v.setVisible(true);
    v.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void loadCombo1() {
    combo1.addItem("letters");
    combo1.addItem("numbers");
}

private void loadCombo2(String seleccionEnCombo1) {
    combo2.removeAllItems();
    if (seleccionEnCombo1.equals("letters")) {
        combo2.addItem("A");
        combo2.addItem("B");
        combo2.addItem("C");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo1.equals("numbers")) {
        combo2.addItem("1");
        combo2.addItem("2");
        combo2.addItem("3");
    }

}

private void loadCombo3(String seleccionEnCombo2) {
    combo3.removeAllItems();
    if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("A")) {
        combo3.addItem("A-1");
        combo3.addItem("A-2");
        combo3.addItem("A-3");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("B")) {
        combo3.addItem("B-1");
        combo3.addItem("B-2");
        combo3.addItem("B-3");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("C")) {
        combo3.addItem("C-1");
        combo3.addItem("C-2");
        combo3.addItem("C-3");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("1")) {
        combo3.addItem("1-a");
        combo3.addItem("1-b");
        combo3.addItem("1-c");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("2")) {
        combo3.addItem("2-a");
        combo3.addItem("2-b");
        combo3.addItem("2-c");
    } else if (seleccionEnCombo2.equals("3")) {
        combo3.addItem("3-a");
        combo3.addItem("3-b");
        combo3.addItem("3-c");
    }   
}
}
```

---

But I get the next Exception when I select the `numbers` value in the `jcombo1`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox.loadCombo3(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:78)
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox.access$3(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:76)
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox$2.actionPerformed(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:40)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeAllItems(Unknown Source)
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox.loadCombo2(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:63)
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox.access$1(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:62)
    at es.mycompany.MyView.ThreeCascadeJComboBox$1.actionPerformed(ThreeCascadeJComboBox.java:30)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: this would be a LOT easier if you formatted the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because at that point `seleccionEnCombo2` is `null`.

You could add a check for `null` in the `combo2` `ActionListener` and it will work fine:

```
if (combo2.getSelectedItem() != null) {
  loadCombo3((String) combo2.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ActionListener` for `combo1` is triggering an `ActionEvent` for `combo2` which will not have any selected item (as it is empty). You could add a check:

```
if (combo2.getSelectedItem() != null) {
    loadCombo3((String) combo2.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other posts have mentioned, the selected value for the combo is null in some cases. This is occurring because you probably do not realize the ActionListener for combo2 is getting called twice. The first time it gets called is during the call to `removeAllElements`. This is where the null value is coming from. The second time is what you are assuming in your code to be the only call--this is in response to both population of the combo box as well as user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the second combo box, that fires the action event for that box (because an action has taken place [actions are not limited to selection].  The 2nd combo box's actionPerformed attempts to load the 3rd combo box based on the 2nd combo box's selection, and there isn't any.  That's your null pointer, the non-existent selection from the second combo box.